# How to get the updated value of an object from IE after form submission?

Tags: vba

I am automating a form submission with VBA and IE. 
I am able to submit a form, however, after form submit, i am not able to get the latest status of the label form the IE Document
Here is the code i am using for the URL http://www.tangoloans.co.uk/brokerform/?affl_id=216

URL = "http://www.tangoloans.co.uk/brokerform/?affl_id=216"
    recordCount = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

```
        Set appIE = New InternetExplorer
        appIE.navigate URL

        Do While appIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.StatusBar = "Waiting ..."
            DoEvents
        Loop

        appIE.Visible = True
        Set Doc = appIE.document

        Doc.getElementById("title").Value = .Range("A" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("fname").Value = .Range("B" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("lname").Value = .Range("C" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("dobDay").Value = .Range("D" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("dobMonth").Value = .Range("E" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("dobYear").Value = .Range("F" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("l_amount").Value = .Range("M" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("l_terms").Value = .Range("N" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("h_phone").Value = .Range("G" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("m_phone").Value = .Range("H" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("address1").Value = .Range("J" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("town_city").Value = .Range("K" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("p_code").Value = .Range("L" & row)
        Doc.getElementById("email").Value = .Range("I" & row)

        If .Range("O" & row) = "Tenant" Then
            Doc.all("owner")(1).Click
        Else
            Doc.all("owner")(0).Click
        End If

        If .Range("P" & row) = "Tenant" Then
            Doc.all("guarantor")(1).Click
        Else
            Doc.all("guarantor")(0).Click
        End If

        Doc.getElementById("contactViaPost").Checked = True
        Doc.getElementById("contactViaEmail").Checked = True
        Doc.getElementById("contactViaPhone").Checked = True
        Doc.getElementById("agreeToTOS").Checked = True

        Doc.getElementById("submit_application").Click

        Do While appIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.StatusBar = "Waiting ..."
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 20, Now)

        Set HCollection = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("h2")

        For Each c In HCollection
            If c.className = "vc_custom_heading" Then
                .Range("Q" & row) = c.innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

however this line

> .Range("Q" & row) = c.innerText

always returns me the old text

I tried increasing wait time, but not luck. Can someone help here

Answer (score 0):

You're the value of `c` in your `For..Each` loop through `HCollection`, which is an object containing tag names (retrieved using `getElementsByTagName`) from **the *`appIE.Document`* object**.

`appIE.Document` is a snapshot of the HTML contained in the `appIE`, current to the last time you "copied" the HTML, which you're doing with the line:

```
Set Doc = appIE.Document
```

Run that line again, and the "snapshot" value of the `.Document` property of the `appIE` object will be "refreshed" to contain the HTML that's *currently* in the  `InternetExplorer` object.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Document` Property** (Windows/IE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752052)
- MSDN : [**Different Ways to Use a Browser** (Windows/IE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952618.aspx)
- Mozilla : [**Document Properties**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document)

Comment: you mean something like this after Application.wait? I tried and its not working
Set Doc = appIE.document
            
Set HCollection = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h2")

Comment: It is difficult to debug without actually doing the process ourselves. Can you post the html post form submit that relates to vc_custom_heading ?